# jquery .text as a conditional

Tags: jquery, text

I have this code: (jquery)

```
    alert($('#feedback').text());
    if ($('#feedback').text() == "") {
        alert("has content");
    } else {
        alert("no content");
    }
```

Which I am using to test the #feedback div for any plan text content. Yet no matter how I format the condition, the else statement always fires regardless of whether I have content or not.

Where am I going wrong here?

html:

```
<div id="feedback" class="hide feedback">
    <p>generated message</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a part of your html

Comment: Other than that you have the texts reversed (it alerts "no content" when you *have* content and vice versa) the code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/PcXKJ/

Comment: Your code looks fine, however your conditional is backwards. http://jsfiddle.net/kAGq4/

Comment: Ok the == should be !=, but this doesn't solve the problem of one or the other blocks of code always firing when they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the HTML example I assume you have something like this when the div is supposed to be empty:

```
<div id="feedback" class="hide feedback">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

In that case the `.text()` of the div is not `""`, it's `"\n\n"` (two line breaks). You need to remove the line breaks with `$.trim()`. (The same is true even if there are no `<p>` tags if the line breaks are there.)

```
if( $.trim( $( '#feedback' ).text() ) == "" ) {
    alert( "no content" );
} else {
    alert( "has content" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Just for checking !*

Check your : `$('#feedback').length` value

```
if ($('#feedback').length>0  && $.trim($('#feedback').text()) != "") {
    alert("has content");
} else {
    alert("no content"); // or no element
}
```

Comment: Hey, the extra length check seems to of caught the problem. cheers!

Comment: It's not the length check but the `$.trim()` part that did it. You don't need to check for the existence of the element since `.text()` returns `""` if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: @Juhana I wanted the condition to fail if there isn't element at all. - just for checking.thats why I wrote _Just for checking_

Comment: It would fail even without the extra check.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if ($('#feedback').text() != "") {
    alert("has content");
} else {
    alert("no content");
}
```

Comment: The problem, as the OP stated, was that the second block was always reached, *regardless of whether `#feedback` was empty or not*.

Comment: @Juhana - and based on the code provided, my answer works. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fTuje/

Comment: See also the OP's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614909/jquery-text-as-a-conditional#comment15378557_11614909): *"Ok the == should be !=, but this doesn't solve the problem of one or the other blocks of code always firing when they shouldn't be."*

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
if ($('#feedback p:empty').length) {
    alert("empty");
} else {
    alert("has content");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is reverted...

```
alert($('#feedback').text());
if ($('#feedback').text() == "") {
    alert("no content");
} else {
    alert("has content");
}
```

Its fixed now :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
if($('#feedback').is(':empty')) {
   alert("no content");
} else {
   alert("has content");
}
```